# How to use Iframes in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webautomation

`<iframe ng-repeat="contentFrame in contentFrames" src="/PrivateArea/MDL_Action/Default.aspx?rid=241&amp;ifrsafe=1" class="tg_pageFrame ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" iframe-onload="contentFrame.pageNavigated()"></iframe>`

how do I switch to this frame in python selenium

I watched some tutorial on youtube and after using control F in elements this iframe is number 10 out of 12 iframes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case there are more then one identical frames you can select required frame by index:

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[9]
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
```